# Neo4j: Native Java API(or equivalent cypher query) in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I was experimenting with Neo4j embedded-db in the past few days for a DEMO and was thoroughly impressed with the Native Java API's for indexing, lucene queries and even managed to do fuzzy search. I then decided to take this POC to production with Spring Data Neo4j 4.0 but ran into issues with Cypher queries and fuzzy search.

My domain class "Team" looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity public class Team {

@GraphId Long nodeId;

/** The team name. */
@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT,indexName = "teamName")
private String teamName;

public Team(){};

public Team(String name){
    this.teamName = name;
}

public void setTeamName(String name){
    this.teamName = name;
}

public String getTeamName(){
    return this.teamName;
}
}
```

I am populating my database as follows:

```
Team lakers = new Team("Los Angeles Lakers");
Team clippers = new Team("Los Angeles Clippers of Anaheim");
Team warriors = new Team("Golden State Warriors");
Team slappers = new Team("Los Angeles Slappers of Anaheim");
Team slippers = new Team("Los Angeles Slippers of Anaheim");

    Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();
    try{

        teamRepository.save(lakers);
        teamRepository.save(clippers);
        teamRepository.save(warriors);
        teamRepository.save(slappers);
        teamRepository.save(slippers);
    }
```

My TeamRepository interface looks like this:

```
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, String>
{
    @Query("MATCH (team:Team) WHERE team.teamName=~{0} RETURN team")
    List<Team> findByTeamName(String query);

}
```

My query looks like:

`List<Team> teams = teamRepository.findByTeamName("The Los Angeles Will be Playing in a state of Golden");`

The above CYPHER query DOES NOT return anything.

I'd like to be able to do a Native Java API type query in Spring like the one below and get the following result.(teamIndex was a full text search index I had created on team names)

`IndexHits<Node> found = teamIndex.query("Team-Names",queryString+"~0.5");`.

Native JAVA API found:

- Los Angeles Lakers
- Los Angeles Clippers of Anaheim
- Golden State Warriors
- Los Angeles Slappers of Anaheim
- Los Angeles Slippers of Anaheim

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is in SDN3

SDN4 doesn't support @Indexed.

There is an IndexRepository with some additional query methods but you can also use cypher like this:

```
public interface TeamRepository extends GraphRepository<Team>
{
    @Query("start team=node:teamName({0}) RETURN team")
    List<Team> findByTeamName(String query);
}
```

Which will send the index-query to Lucene.

Comment: With SDN4 fulltext additions are deferred: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#_full_text_indexes. But Neo4j 2.3 will add more string lookup functionality so that most should work out of the box.

Comment: The search  teamRepository.findByTeamName("The Los Angeles Will be Playing in a state of Golden") for the cypher @Query("start team=node:teamName({0}) RETURN team") throws a NPE org.apache.lucene.util.SimpleStringInterner.intern(SimpleStringInterner.java:54). I found similar threads: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/112078-repository-derived-query-not-working-with-strings-that-have-spaces. Also if teamName is not Indexed, I get an error stating that Index 'teamName' does not exist