# Neo4j: Lucene query syntax in SDN4

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Can someone please explain the appropriate Cypher Query syntax to get the following result from the below mentioned Repository query ? The below mentioned team names have been saved to the repository.

- Los Angeles Lakers
- Los Angeles Clippers of Anaheim
- Golden State Warriors
- Los Angeles Slappers of Anaheim
- Los Angeles Slippers of Anaheim

I was suggested the below Cypher which ended up in a NPE.
[Neo4j: Native Java API(or equivalent cypher query) in Spring Data Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350710/neo4j-native-java-apior-equivalent-cypher-query-in-spring-data-neo4j)

```
    //Repository     
    public interface TeamRepository extends GraphRepository<Team>
    {
        @Query("start team=node:teamName({0}) RETURN team")
        List<Team> findByTeamName(String query);
    }
```

The below call throws a NPE when invoked as follows:

```
teamRepository.findByTeamName("The Los Angeles Will be Playing in a state of Golden");
```

NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:675)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.directv.service.Sports.main(Sports.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SimpleStringInterner.intern(SimpleStringInterner.java:54)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.StringHelper.intern(StringHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.Term.<init>(Term.java:38)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:643)
```

Comment: This rather looks like a lucene issue with your query string. Make sure to quote (backslash) spaces.

Comment: Can you share your lucene query string that caused this error?

Comment: @Michael Hunger The query string is just plain text: `teamRepository.findByTeamName("The Los Angeles Will be Playing in a state of Golden");`

Comment: Unfortunately you have to escape spaces there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I was able to resolve this issue. As @Michael Hunger pointed out, this is an issue with the embedded space characters in the query.The appropriate query is:
`@Query("START team=node:teamName('teamName:(*The Los Angeles Will be Playing in a state of Golden*)') RETURN team")`